# RealtimeAnalyzer memory

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I'm trying to write a visualizer for Spotify using the Processing library.

But I have a problem with the **audio.RealtimeAnalyzer** class.

```
var analyzer = audio.RealtimeAnalyzer.forPlayer(models.player);
analyzer.addEventListener('audio', function(data){ ... });
```

If I let this run for an hour Spotify is using more then 1.5GB of memory and eventually crashes. Is there any possibility for dumping or freeing all this unnecessary memory?
Or can I solve this issue with using an other class?

Comment: Repro'd - using the sample code from https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-audio.html my memory usage is growing about 25 MB/minute.  Reloading my App doesn't release the memory.

Comment: window.gc() doesn't seem to be an available function (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950394/forcing-garbage-collection-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one with problem. Even when I use the visualizer that Spotify itself have built the memory keeps growing.
[link](http://labs.spotify.com/2013/11/14/announcing-spotify-visualization-api-beta/)

Comment: http://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/0-9-4-BufferAnalyzer-and-RealtimeAnalyzer-memory-leak/m-p/559596/highlight/true#M63752

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I first noticed that as well. I posted it as a bug under their github app.

https://github.com/spotify/visualizer-app

Perhaps if you added your input they would see it's really hindering dev work.