# Chrome DevTools, open for 15 minutes, tab runs out of memory

Tags: out-of-memory, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a chrome extension for a foreign website (I don't control it) that uses Lightstreamer to send large amounts of data to the browser.

Without DevTools opened, the website runs fine for a long duration (ex: 8 hours)

When I open DevTools, it runs out of memory after approx 15 minutes.

I watch Chrome's Task Mgr with the column "JavaScript memory" displayed, and I can observe the memory increasing.

The JS mem column displays 2 values, a total and a live amount. They both grow until the tab dies, and the DevTools window closes automatically.

If I close the DevTools tab early, Task Mgr shows the memory value fall drastically, as if garbage collection finally kicks in.

This only occurs on this single website, so it might be using bad coding practices, but since I can't control it, it makes debugging my extension painful.

I recently reset DevTools settings and restarted the entire computer, but the symptoms persist.

I'm wondering if others have experienced this and if there is anything I can do to minimize this issue, other than closing the DevTools tab every 5 minutes to save the tab?

thanks

Comment: I can absolutely confirm when in Linux and Windows, using anything that loops through various sized memory objects (such as displaying video), the Dev-Tools can ramp up it's memory usage infinitely. To test, I used a simple load and show loop test, of varying images to a DIV. If I comment out the display line, no problem. If I disable DevTools, no problem. I then tried in Electron 4, 6 and 7 for differing V8 versions, then a new PC, new Windows, new Ubuntu, same result, but for me, it is tied down to the display of variable sized images. (Bytes not dimensions).

Comment: I have similar issue with Chrome 89-90 and 92 in Canary. In 88 it was kind of OK. But after 89 in my app, only when dev tools is open. Every clicks costs around 250MB of memory :)

Answer (score 2):

i found this thread, which seems to have some suggestions.

[Forcing garbage collection in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950394/forcing-garbage-collection-in-google-chrome)

I will try later on to manually force chrome to collect garbage