# How to clear closed RTCPeerConnection >> [with WORKAROUND]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, microsoft-edge, chromium

This is the old famous Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825576

The error is: `Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Cannot create so many PeerConnections`

Now because Edge is based on Chromium, not only Chrome is affected by this bug making things even worst.

We need to find a way to force Garbage Collector cycle.

I posted my current workaround but i'd be glad to find a better workaround, if any...?

Answer (score 4):

After some times trying to figure it out, the best workaround i found to force/invoke Garbage Collector is to create then revoke some data buffers.

Simplest fix on Chrome/Edge was to use:

```
URL.revokeObjectURL(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([new ArrayBuffer(5e+7)]))) // 50Mo buffer
```

**BUT** then, this would introduce memory leaks on Firefox.
On Firefox, it seems like ObjectURL cannot be revoked without being bound to DOM element. Cannot find anything about it in the [spec](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-revokeObjectURL).

So cross browser solution (Chrome/Edge/Firefox, other browsers not tested), would be:

```
queueMicrotask(() => { // || >> requestIdleCallback
  let img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([new ArrayBuffer(5e+7)])); // 50Mo
  img.onerror = function() {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
    img = null
  }
})
```

Here is a sample working code fixing WebRTC bug:

```js
var i = 1;

function peer() {
  var peer = new RTCPeerConnection();
  setTimeout(() => {
    peer.close();
    peer = null;
  }, 10);
  console.log(i++);
  if (!(i % 20)) {
    // try to invoke GC on each 20ish iteration
    queueMicrotask(() => { 
      let img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([new ArrayBuffer(5e+7)])); // 50Mo or less or more depending as you wish to force/invoke GC cycle run
      img.onerror = function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
        img = null
      }
    })
  }
}

setInterval(peer, 20);
```

Comment: can you add that (terrible but if it works...) workaround to the chrome issue please?

Comment: I have implemented this answer but didn't work, the error still appeared

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the chromium process, you can actually expose the garbage collector to javascript. See the edit on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13951759/1563399.

The edit states that you can add `--js-flags="--expose-gc"` to your launch flags. Which will then expose a global function called `gc` that can be called to invoke the garbage collector.

I tried using the solution [A. Wolff posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66546935/1563399). But this seems to cause a memory leak in my embedded raspberry pi project.