# DOMException: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Cannot create so many PeerConnections

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora, agora-implementation

I am using agora to make a video calling app. I am using the [agora-rtc-sdk-ng](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-rtc-sdk-ng) package. I am following [this doc](https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=web) for my project. I have converted this into a nextjs project.
But I am facing this error when I rejoin a call.
**DOMException: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': Cannot create so many PeerConnections**

How do i solve it?

I did some research and found [this doc](https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/B7W5y0LbmSQ/m/uspmgatVAwAJ)
But I can't understand where this fits in the code i am using.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same error with the Agora RTC SDK in my React Js project.
I searched the internet and found that it's related to the browser garbage collector. In my assumption, it could happen to any WebRTC library like Agora.
I found that this answer about handling the garbage collector for WebRTC https://stackoverflow.com/a/66546935/8339172 helped some people.